# React-Native :: WebView :: Some Blank Pages With No Apparent Pattern

Tags: webview, android-emulator, android-webview, react-native

[ ] ***`EDIT:`*** **On the third reboot of my Mac, spontaneous self-fix of problem not fixed by prior two reboots. So if anyone encounters this issue, just keep rebooting until it works, apparently.**

For our React-Native app, currently only testing against the Android Emulator environment, all websites are accessible using the Browser app on the emulated device, but within our `<WebView />` component, only some websites render, and there are no error messages until a timeout error (which takes a while), after which the "Oh no!" and Proxy object are logged, with a Yellowbox message.

I do not have direct control over the Android (Java) code, but any potential solutions requiring changes to that side of the project are also welcome.

And when the page load fails on Network A, the output seen in [`React-Native-Debugger`](https://github.com/jhen0409/react-native-debugger) is:

```
Encountered an error loading page
{
    "canGoForward": false,
    "code": -2,
    "canGoBack": false,
    "description": "net::ERR_NAME_NOT_RESOLVED",
    "loading": false,
    "title": "",
    "url": "https://www.stallman.org",
    "target": 2
}
```

And both the "starting!" and "ending!" console logs fire.

On Network B, the Yellowbox never appears, and the "starting!" message fires, but not the "ending!" message, even after waiting a full 5 minutes.

* * * *My hunch (based on some other eyes on the problem) is that this is an issue related to redirects not being handled properly.* * * *

**Does anyone have an idea of how to solve this problem, and what might be at the root?**

Thank you.

---

Android Emulator details:

```
Name: Nexus_5X_API_23

CPU/ABI: Google APIs Intel Atom (x86_64)

Path: /Users/$USER/.android/avd/Nexus_5X_API_23.avd // $USER = user

Target: google_apis [Google APIs] (API level 23)

Skin: nexus_5x

SD Card: 100M

hw.dPad: no

hw.lcd.height: 1920

runtime.network.speed: full

hw.accelerometer: yes

hw.device.name: Nexus 5X

vm.heapSize: 256

skin.dynamic: yes

hw.device.manufacturer: Google

hw.lcd.width: 1080

hw.gps: yes

hw.initialOrientation: Portrait

image.androidVersion.api: 23

hw.audioInput: yes

image.sysdir.1: system-images/android-23/google_apis/x86_64/

tag.id: google_apis

showDeviceFrame: yes

hw.camera.back: virtualscene

hw.mainKeys: no

AvdId: Nexus_5X_API_23

hw.camera.front: emulated

hw.lcd.density: 420

avd.ini.displayname: Nexus 5X API 23

hw.arc: false

hw.gpu.mode: auto

hw.device.hash2: MD5:bc5032b2a871da511332401af3ac6bb0

hw.ramSize: 1536

hw.trackBall: no

PlayStore.enabled: false

fastboot.forceColdBoot: no

hw.battery: yes

hw.cpu.ncore: 4

hw.sdCard: yes

tag.display: Google APIs

runtime.network.latency: none

hw.keyboard: yes

hw.sensors.proximity: yes

disk.dataPartition.size: 800M

hw.sensors.orientation: yes

avd.ini.encoding: UTF-8

hw.gpu.enabled: yes
```

Project details:

```
  "dependencies": {
    "@types/react-redux": "^6.0.6",
    "bind": "^0.1.7",
    "deep-freeze": "0.0.1",
    "i18next": "^11.6.0",
    "prop-types": "^15.6.2",
    "react-i18next": "^7.11.0",
    "react-redux": "^5.0.7",
    "redux": "^4.0.0",
    "redux-thunk": "^2.3.0"
  },
  "peerDependencies": {
    "react": "16.0.0",
    "react-native": "0.51.0",
    "react-native-svg": "^6.4.1",
    "react-native-svg-loader": "^0.1.5",
    "svgs": "^3.2.1"
  },
```

(Pared down) Component code:

```
import * as React from 'react';
import { Component } from 'react';
import { WebViewUriSource } from 'react-native';
import { Text, View, WebView } from 'react-native';

import { WebViewProps } from '../prop-types';

export class WebViewComponent extends Component<WebViewProps, {}> {
    public onMessage = (event) => {
        console.log(event);
    }

    public render () {
        const jsCode = 'console.log("Hello World!")';

        return (
            <WebView
                source={{ uri: 'https://www.stallman.org' }}
                onLoadStart={() => console.log('starting!')}
                onLoadEnd={() => console.log('ending!')}
                style={{ flex: 1 }}
                javaScriptEnabled={true}
                mixedContentMode={'always'}
                domStorageEnabled={true}
                scalesPageToFit={true}
                onMessage={this.onMessage}
                injectedJavaScript={jsCode}
                onError={(x) => console.log('Oh no!', x)}
                renderError={() => {
                    return (
                        <View style={{ flex: 1 }}>
                            <Text>
                                Some Error Happened
                            </Text>
                        </View>);
                }}
            />
        );
    }
}
```

The props passed to `<WebView />` are largely in place as a result of my previous searches through documentation, Github issues, and other SO articles. So far, none has solved the problem.